# Nextjs: a way to avoid external link

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, kiosk

we have created a WebApp with nextjs/reactjs for a Kiosk mode of chrome but we want to prevent to go to any external URL different from the current domain.
There's some way with a Chrome configuration o with a middleware in nextjs?

For many components we have a Link method to find the url and prevent click, but on free content this is not possible

Thank's :)

Comment: Hi Skiddolo, what is free content?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i mean a field with html inside